# What's a more efficient way of appending more items to a string depending on a list's length?

Tags: python, list

This is what I have right now.
What I would like is for the string to concatenate more depending on the length of the "top_line". So if the top line has 1 item, the "full_top_line" and "full_second_line" and "full_dashes_line" also only add 1 item

```
if len(top_line) == 1:
    full_top_line = top_line[0]
    full_second_line = second_line[0]
    full_dashes_line = dash[0]
if len(top_line) == 2:
    full_top_line = top_line[0] + "    " + top_line[1]
    full_second_line = second_line[0] + "    " + second_line[1]
    full_dashes_line = dash[0] + "    " + dash[1]
if len(top_line) == 3:
    full_top_line = top_line[0] + "    " + top_line[1] + "    " + top_line[2]
    full_second_line = second_line[0] + "    " + second_line[1] + "    " + second_line[2]
    full_dashes_line = dash[0] + "    " + dash[1] + "    " + dash[2]
if len(top_line) == 4:
    full_top_line = top_line[0] + "    " + top_line[1] + "    " + top_line[2] + "    " + top_line[3]
    full_second_line = second_line[0] + "    " + second_line[1] + "    " + second_line[2] + "    " + second_line[3]
    full_dashes_line = dash[0] + "    " + dash[1] + "    " + dash[2] + "    " + dash[3]
if len(top_line) == 5:
    full_top_line = top_line[0] + "    " + top_line[1] + "    " + top_line[2] + "    " + top_line[3] + "    " + top_line[4]
    full_second_line = second_line[0] + "    " + second_line[1] + "    " + second_line[2] + "    " + second_line[3] + "    " + second_line[4]
    full_dashes_line = dash[0] + "    " + dash[1] + "    " + dash[2] + "    " + dash[3] + "    " + dash[4]
```

Comment: The code isn't appending to a list, it is *joining* strings. Are you aware of ``str.join``?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list `comprehension` with `join()` method instead

```
full_top_line = " ".join([top_line[i] for i in range(len(top_line))])

full_second_line = " ".join([second_line[i] for i in range(len(top_line))])

full_dashes_line = " ".join([dash[i] for i in range(len(top_line))])
```

Comment: What's the point of the list comprehensions? If you want to limit the length ``" ".join(second_line[:len(top_line)])`` should be enough.